# Как приостановить выполнение функции в JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Как приостановить выполнение  функции в `JavaScript`?
Т.е.

```
команда 1;
команда 2;
ПАУЗА 5 сек;
команда 3;//команда не выполняется, пока не выполнится ПАУЗА 5 сек;
```

*UPD1:*
Если неизвестно, сколько пауза будет? Т.е. примерно так:

```
команда3 -> установить паузу;
... ... ...
команда3 -> отменить паузу
```

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста: остановить функцию или код в целом?

Comment: Нет. Только функцию.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как выполнить задержку в Javascript?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/251150/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b2-javascript)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function firstStep(){
}
function secondStep(){
}

firstStep();
setTimeout('secondStep()',5000);//через 5 секунд выполнится вторая часть кода.
```

Пример:

```js
var element = document.getElementById('clckbl');
var warn = setTimeout('function2()', 3000);
var clickOnTime = true;
element.onclick = function() {
  if (clickOnTime) {
    clearTimeout(warn);
    alert('Успел!');
  } else {
    alert('Время истекло, поздно кликать');
  }
};

function function2() {
  alert('время истекло');
  clickOnTime = false;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 500px; height: 500px; background-color: #face8D" id="clckbl">Успей на меня нажать за три секунды!</div>
```

Comment: А если неизвестно, сколько времени надо ждать? См. в вопрос.

Comment: !!!!!!!! ах вот вы о чем. Тут вообще все проще некуда:  
команда3 -> secondStep();  
тупо, третья команда исполняет функцию второго шага.

Пример:
element.onclick = function{ secondStep(); };

Comment: Извините за безграмотность, можно показать пример с Timeout подробнее? (и внести в ответ). Т.е. пока не придет команда clearTimeout, тормозить функцию step3.

Comment: Ловите пример.

Comment: Ё! СПАСИБО за отличную и скорую помощь в решении!