# Как выполнить задержку в Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Как выполнить задержку без запуска функции?т.е. Можно ли примерно так setTimeout(, 100) допустим. или как в паскали delay();

Comment: жду предложений))заранее спасибо)

Comment: что конкретно Вы хотели бы сделать? Просто чтобы ничего не выполнялось некоторое время?

Comment: точно!чтобы программа просто застыла на 2 секунды

Comment: Я бы предложил в данном случае спроектировать свою программу так, чтобы использовать setTimeout(), с вызовом функций и прочее. Потому что javascript выполняется на стороне клиента и любая задержка в выполнении отражается на продуктивности самого браузера, т.к. браузер попросту дает очередность каждому процессу и ждет его завершения, чтобы передать эту очередность кому-то другому. Очередь одна. И как Вы наверное догадываетесь, попытка "заморозить" выполнение программы приведет к "заморозке" всего браузера, что не допустимо с точки зрения пользователя.

Comment: тогда другой вопрос.по той же теме.Вот. В javascript область видимости ограничивается функцией, правильно? как передать аргумент в функцию внутри setTimeout()?т.е. допустим, 
    setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById("mark").innerHTML=i;},2000)
прошу помочь)я начинающий)))

Comment: достаточно переменную i декларировать за пределами этой функции.

Comment: но если в цикле то надо генерировать функцию в момент задания интервала

Comment: setTimeout(function(){ 
        foo(i); 
    }, 2000);
    function foo(i){
        document.getElementById("mark").innerHTML=i;
    };

Так?

Comment: нет, тут шаманство

    setTimeout(gen_foo(i),2000);
    function gen_foo(i) {
       return function foo(){
          document.getElementById("mark").innerHTML=i;
       };
    }

Comment: [тут ](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/3aWcj/) продвинутое шаманство :)  - сделаем генератор подходящий для любой функции объявленной в области видимости цикла (типа прокси поддерживающее и this и аргументы)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"Задержки" - это то, что у девушек может случиться, с js  в этом случае всё несколько иначе.
Приостановить выполнение javascript кода можно с использованием функции alert, confirm, prompt (еще "debugger", но это совсем другая история).
Во всех других случаях используйте "setTimeout" и callbacks.

Что же до Вашего попроса с областью видимости:

```
var i = 'hi, there!';
setTimeout(function(){ document.getElementById("mark").innerHTML=i;},2000);
```

А вот такое прекращайте писать:

> нужно i передать.прошу помочь)я начинающий)))

Тут или помогут, или не помогут, надоело читать из вопроса в вопрос эту фразу.

Comment: я вот не пойму я там в комментах зря что-ли распинался ?

    var i = 'hi, there!';
    setTimeout(function(){ document.getElementById("mark").innerHTML=i;},2000);
    i='Ooops !'

Comment: да, зря
это не ответ на вопрос начинающего, только тумана навели

Comment: ок следующий вопрос от него был бы "а я тут переменную передаю, а у неё только последний аргумент работает" я же показал вам пример в котором ваш код не работает. и где извините у меня туман ? по-моему весьма доходчиво все объяснил.

Comment: если эта задача представляет академический интересе - согласен.
В этом случае Ваш цикл можно обернуть в функцию и использовать как Dikaz изначально хотел:
uglyTimeout(delayTime); // wait some time

Но честь по чести я бы хотел разобраться, в каком случае может понадобиться останавливать выполение js кода - пока на практике не встречался с такой необходимостью.

Comment: а туман появляется, когда начинается рефакторинг чужого кода.
Сидеть и разбираться, что пол экрана делают ничего не очень приятно

Comment: @eicto, может вот это

    document.getElementById("mark").innerHTML=i; //эта строчка выполнится с задержкой в 2 секунды


сбивает с толку?

 Ведь каждая такая строчка (см. Ваш коммент выше) выполнится через i \* 2 сек.

А вообще, для людей не очень знакомых с динамическими языками подобное шаманство надо бы разжевывать (особенно с аргументами для генерации функции в текущем контексте).

Comment: я же написал, что про контест это просто next level, можно юзать копипастой. ну а насчет этой строки, наверное плохо выразился, 

    //выполнится 100 раз с интервалом в две секунды, 

лучше ?
@avp отвечу здесь :)
конечно в две, первый вызов случится через 2 секунды, второй через 2*2=4 секунды, 3й - через 2*3=6 секунд. 6-4=4-2=2-0=2 ;)

Comment: Разве в две?

    for (var i=1;i<101;i++)
      setTimeout(gen_foo(i),2000*i);

IMHO для каждого вызова таймаут разный.

Comment: @ESTET - интерес не академический, ведь знание о работе асинхронных функций полезно и при работе с ajax и при работе с базами данных на nodejs и при обработке  событий.

Comment: А `setTimeout()` это и есть обработка асинхронного события. Просто мы сами планируем момент его наступления.

@eicto, я тоже отвечу здесь.

Вот теперь всем очевидно.

Comment: очевидно, что вместо setInterval  у нас собственный велосипед с циклом и setTimeout. А говорите, что не академический.

Насчет занудствования: минимум "2секунды+время инициализации генератора"

Answer (score 2):

```
const delay = async (ms) => await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
```

Использование:

```
const actionWithDelay = delay(1000).then(() => some actions);
```

или

```
const actionWithDelay = async () => {
    await delay(2000);
    some actions;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант:

```
function sleep(millis) {
    var t = (new Date()).getTime();
    var i = 0;
    while (((new Date()).getTime() - t) < millis) {
        i++;
    }
}
```

И вызов:

```
sleep(2000); //Время в миллисекундах
```

Comment: @eicto ну погодите, какой вопрос такое и решение.

Comment: ну знаете, один индус тоже sleep(86400) вызывал, когда надо было получить дату на след день...

Comment: Чтобы чуть лучше понять масштаб трагедии, немного сухой статистики: при выполнении двухсекундного sleep объект Date был создан 3 443 905 раз. Столько же раз у него была вызвана функция getTime. Разумеется, сам браузер повис на всё те же две секунды (насколько знаю, этой проблемы лишен только Chrome, у которого отдельный процесс на каждую вкладку). Иными словами, чтобы ничего не делать n секунд, ему требуется на эти самые n секунд зависнуть. Про мелочи вроде переменной i, которая не используется, но упорно инкрементируется, я упоминать не буду..хотя нет, уже упомянул

Comment: @DreamChild, а CPU какой?

На самом деле очень шустрый интерпретатор JS.

Я попробовал аналогичный цикл на Си (чисто вызов time()) на 

    Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5520  @ 2.27GHz

получилось на десятке запусков от 12054963 до 17573157 циклов.

Comment: Ну уж что спросили то и ответил. Понятно что это извращенный метод, но если человек не умеет с callbacks работать.

Comment: Intel Core i5-2500, 3.3 GHz

Comment: >Ну уж что спросили то и ответил

забавная логика - человек не умеет делать правильно, так пусть и дальше делает неправильно, а мы ему в этом поможем, дав худший из вариантов

Comment: "Как делать правильно" человеку подсказали выше.