# Приостановка выполнения javascript скрипта

Tags: javascript, settimeout, alert, prompt

Да очень похожий вопрос на эти два:

[Как приостановить выполнение функции в JavaScript?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/35579/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B2-javascript)

[Как выполнить задержку в Javascript?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/251150/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B2-javascript)

Суть в следующем, необходимо при наведении мыши на ячейку таблицы, выполнить некий скрипт (показ превьюшки). Так вот, если беспорядочно двигать мышью (то есть резко протащить по всем ячейкам или что то подобное), происходит вылет (тут все ясно почему), вопрос не в этом. Как ограничить выполнение скрипта. То есть нужно чтобы скрипт выполнялся через некоторое время после события, и только в том случае если указатель мыши сохранил свое положение, после установленного промежутка времени. При этом `setTimeOut` не подходит, потому что положение указателя мыши определить из функции вызываемой как вторичная как в первом посте, нет возможности. Функции `alert`, `confirm`, `promp` требуют участия пользователя, что тоже не приемлемо.

Конечно есть идейка как нибудь забубенить, что то типа скрытого `confirm`, при помощи `setTimeOut` вызвать событие через нужное время, которое юзала бы кнопочку confirma. Но это нелепый костыль, и вообще не знаю получится ли.

Возможно уже есть элегантные костыли, решающие подобную задачу.

Comment: нельзя сделать _скрытый_ confirm.

Comment: да похоже на то что нужно. Возможно стоит внести поправку в вопрос.Я решил задачу по своему: так как скрипт необходим для отображения информации из таблицы postgreSQL, а сам проект написан на .Net MVC, в котором пока без js не обойтись. Проблема была в беспорядочном обращении к базе данных, что попросту вырубало соединение. Я реализовал блокировку обращения к базе данных, на некоторый промежуток времени, соответственно если данных нет то окно с подсказкой Razor пропускает, а в js реализовал проверку на существования слушателя события. Но все равно спасибо, будет уроком.