# Паузы в методе vue, пирамиды ханоя

Tags: vue.js

Vue рендерит пирамидки ханоя, алгоритм в методах перекладывает пирамидки. Не соображу как воткнуть setTimeout, чтобы каждый шаг была задержка, а то пирамидки переставляются мгновенно. В ванильном js с setTimeout все сработает, а если вставить его в методс vue, необхобимый результат не получаю, вопрос больше в том, как в функцию из метода запускатьт с задержкой (чтобы при рекурсивном вызове эта задержка срабатывала всегда)

```
 methods: {
hanoi: function (n, from, to) {
//!Сюда бы паузу!
  if (n == 1) {
    this.store[to - 1].unshift(this.store[from - 1].shift());
    console.log("move disk 1! from pin " + from + " to pin " + to);
  } else {
    let tmp = 6 - from - to;
    this.hanoi(n - 1, from, tmp);
    this.store[to - 1].unshift(this.store[from - 1].shift());
    console.log("move disk " + n + " from pin " + from + " to pin " + to);
    this.hanoi(n - 1, tmp, to);
      }
    },
  }
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как выполнить задержку в Javascript?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/251150/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b2-javascript)

Comment: Сделайте функцию async, и используйте await + библиотеку delay или аналог

Comment: Вы имеете в виду при помощи await ждать паузу? Я попробую. 
А по синтаксису будет что-то вроде: "hanoi: async function (n, from, to) {...}"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так работает идеально:

```
historyLog: function () {
      for (let i = 0; i < this.xxx.length; i++) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          //Код
         
          );
        }, 1000 * i); //скорость
      }

},
```