# Пауза в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, вконтакте

Пишy cкpипт для пpиглaшeния нeкoтopыx yчacтникoв гpyппы нa вcтpeчи.
Пoдcкaжитe, пoжaлyйcтa, пoчeмy нe paбoтaeт пayзa?
VK oпpeдeляeт чтo дeйcтвия дeлaeт poбoт:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name Hello World
// @namespace Hello
// @version 0.01
// @description инвайтинг
// @include https://vk.com/friends?act=invite&group_id=1235678&section=members
// ==/UserScript==

function pause(ms)
{
var date = new Date();
var curDate = null;
do { curDate = new Date(); }
while(curDate-date < ms); }

alert('start');
pause(2000);

var res = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for(i=0; i < res.length; i++)
{
    if(res[i].href == "https://vk.com/id11111111");
    {
        let bt = res[i].parentNode.parentNode.querySelector('.flat_button');
        Friends.inviteToGroup(bt, 45454545, 34343434, 0, '45454545')
    }
}

alert('start');
pause(2000);

var res = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for(i=0; i < res.length; i++)
{
    if(res[i].href == "https://vk.com/22222222222");
    {
        let bt = res[i].parentNode.parentNode.querySelector('.flat_button');
        Friends.inviteToGroup(bt, 45454545, 45454545, 1, '45454545')
    }
}

alert('start');
pause(2000);;
```

```html
<div class="friends_user_row clear_fix" id="random">

  <div class="friends_photo_wrap" onmouseover="uiPhotoZoom.over(this, random)">
    <a class="friends_photo _online" href="/id1111111"><img class="friends_photo_img" alt="иван иванов" src="https://pp.me/123.jpg"></a>
  </div>
  
  <div class="friends_controls">
  <button class="flat_button button_small button_wide" onclick="return Friends.inviteToGroup(this, random, random, 0, 'random')">Выслать приглашение</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Паузы в js по-моему нету. WScript.Sleep есть в хосте (не в HTML) вам нужно `window.setTimeout` использовать. Цикл - приведёт к "зависанию" - т.е. пока не отработает скрипт - форма не отрисуется. Возможно где-то можно рефреш влепить - незнаю, да и не лучшая идея.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как приостановить выполнение функции в JavaScript?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/35579/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b2-javascript)

Answer (score -1):

"Паузы в js по-моему нету"-глупости! Паузы в javascript  очень интересная штука. Всегда можно обыграть эту паузу по разному. Главное понять, что скрипт как запустился, так и работает до конца. Он не может зависнуть. Другое дело дать ему "дурную, но не сложную работу" которую он будет повторять несколько раз со встроенным Settimeout. Вот пример:

```
    //ведро  дурной работы(20 х 100 мс=2 сек)
var countColor=20;
var logoLam1 = document.getElementById("logo1"),
logoLam1Change = document.getElementById("logo2");
    logoLam1.style.opacity = 1;
    logoLam1Change.style.opacity=0;
    var logoLam1Opacity = window.getComputedStyle(logoLam1).opacity;
    var Lam1Opacity = parseInt(logoLam1Opacity.substr(0, logoLam1Opacity.length));
/*Два рисунка наложенных один на другой. Функция уменьшает непрозрачность одного, увеличивая непрозрачность другого*/
 function changeColor() {
//Если Непрозрачность первого рисунка выше 0 и нет дурной работы то:
        if (Lam1Opacity> 0&&countColor==0) {
            Lam1Opacity -= 0.1;
            Lam1Opacity= Lam1Opacity.toFixed(1);
            logoLam1.style.opacity = +Lam1Opacity;
            logoLam1Change.style.opacity=1-Lam1Opacity;
            setTimeout(changeColor, 100);
        }
//другое если непрозрачность первого рисунка  больше 0 и есть дурная работа то:
else if(Lam1Opacity> 0&&countColor>0){
            countColor-=1;
/*запуск этой же функции через 100 мс*/
            setTimeout(changeColor, 100);
        }
 changeColor();
```

Как мы видим, паузу все таки можно сделать )))
Если немного разжевал вопрос, повышайте репутацию тому, кто вам помог, иначе очень лень писать за просто так)

Comment: Это не пауза, а таймер.

Comment: Объективно для  пользователя сайта это пауза, а не таймер) Проходит около 2 секунд до выполнения основного кода.  Аналогично этому примеру можно соорудить  "таймер" паузу под свои нужды)