# Javacript таймаут в запросе

Tags: javascript, json

Нужно реализовать таймаут в 1 секунду в цикле. Пробовал через setTimeout, но не пошло

```
   for(i=0;i<ln.length;i++)
    {
    // Здесь нужен таймаут в 1 секунду 
    var req="https://api.exmpent.com/?user = ln[i]"
    $.ajax({
        url : req,
        type : "GET",
        dataType : "jsonp",
        success : function(msg){
        console.log(msg.response);
        }
    });

    }
```

Comment: Сколько приблизительно раз повторяется цикл? (+ошибка в условие цикла)

Comment: Исправил ошибку. Повторяется 80-350раз

Comment: `setInterval` то вас чем не устраивает?

Comment: Вот ещё подобный вопрос: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/35579/183314

Comment: setInterval зависает код а setTimeout не дает результата

Comment: @МиколаКікець что на него смотреть-то, он тут не к месту.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

если необходимо отправить `N` ajax-запросов с некоторым интервалом, то вы вполне можете воспользоваться функция `setInterval()` и завершить ее выполнение с помощью `clearInterval()` по достижению нужного числа итераций.

```js
var idx = 0;  
var iid = null;

function doSomething(){
    $("<li>").text("$.ajax(): " + idx++).appendTo("ul");     // отправить $.post/$.get
    
    if(idx == 20){   // конец цикла
        clearInterval(iid);
    }
}


iid = setInterval(doSomething, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul></ul>
```