# Таймер/задержка/delay присвоения css свойства в js

Tags: javascript

Привет гуру, помогите.
JS вообще не знаю :)
Но нужно! дабы свойство style.opacity = '1'; добавилось через секунду/две
После клика все выполняется, а кнопки прев и некст появились через секунду

```
function hideSlider () {
    var featureBlock = document.getElementById('featured');
    var prev = document.getElementById('prevlink');
    var next = document.getElementById('nextlink')
    var hideButton = document.getElementById('hideSlide');

    if (featureBlock.style.height == '0px' || featureBlock.style.display == "none") {

        sessionStorage.setItem("isHidden", false);
        prev.style.height = '40px';
        next.style.height = '40px';
        prev.style.opacity = '1';
        next.style.opacity = '1';
        featureBlock.style.height = '300px';
        document.getElementById('hide').style.opacity = '1';
        document.getElementById('show').style.opacity = '0';
        hideButton.style.backgroundImage="";
        featureBlock.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        sessionStorage.setItem("isHidden", true);
        featureBlock.style.height = '0px';
        prev.style.height = '0px';
        next.style.height = '0px';
        prev.style.opacity = '0';
        next.style.opacity = '0';
        document.getElementById('hide').style.opacity = '0';
        document.getElementById('show').style.opacity = '1';
        hideButton.style.backgroundImage="";
    }

}
```

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону `setTimeout` и `setInterval`

Comment: [Javacript таймаут в запросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/632439/javacript-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%83%D1%82-%D0%B2-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5)

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout помог, спасибо!

```
function hideSlider () {
var featureBlock = document.getElementById('featured');
var prev = document.getElementById('prevlink');
var next = document.getElementById('nextlink')
var hideButton = document.getElementById('hideSlide');

if (featureBlock.style.height == '0px' || featureBlock.style.display == "none") {

    sessionStorage.setItem("isHidden", false);
    prev.style.height = '25px';
    next.style.height = '25px';


    function opac() {
      prev.style.opacity = '1';
      next.style.opacity = '1';
    }
    setTimeout(opac, 1500);


    featureBlock.style.height = '300px';
    document.getElementById('hide').style.opacity = '1';
    document.getElementById('show').style.opacity = '0';
    hideButton.style.backgroundImage="";
    featureBlock.style.display = "block";
} else {
    sessionStorage.setItem("isHidden", true);
    featureBlock.style.height = '0px';
    prev.style.height = '0px';
    next.style.height = '0px';
    prev.style.opacity = '0';
    next.style.opacity = '0';
    document.getElementById('hide').style.opacity = '0';
    document.getElementById('show').style.opacity = '1';
    hideButton.style.backgroundImage="";
}
```

}